# How can I reduce the tickmarks on my scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot for a project comparing Win Percentage and Three Point Attempts, issue is my plot has way too many tickmarks and I don't know how to reduce the tickmarks.

Code:
NBA_team_data %>% ggplot(aes(x = X.13, y = X.7)) + geom_point() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.1, hjust = 0.5))

I tried scale_x_continous but that didnt work since it gave me an error saying "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Comment: use `dput(df)` to show dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can try using scale_x_discrete()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).